# gstreamer plugin development issue, gst-inspect says: undefined symbol: gst_video_format_new_caps

Tags: linux, linker, makefile, shared-libraries, gstreamer

I need to develop a gstreamer source element, so after running a script to generate plug-in sources and adding some basic boilerplate code, I got my plug-in to build, however when trying to load it from gst-inspect tool, I get:

**(gst-plugin-scanner:10260): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib64/gstreamer-0.10/libgstbcmdec.so': /usr/lib64/gstreamer-0.10/libgstbcmdec.so: undefined symbol: gst_video_format_new_caps**

I found that this symbol should be in gstreamer-plugins-base so I double-checked that its already installed. Also added **-lgstvideo-0.10** to the Makefile.am (so added to GST_LIBS) however this doesnt help. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

I am working on Fedora core 14, 64 bit, and have the latest gstreamer-* packages (used yum).

Comment: Does /usr/lib64/libgstvideo-0.10.so exist on your system? That seems to be where the function lives.

Answer (score 1):

What is your exact Makefile.am? Is it looking like this?

libgstbcmdec_la_LIBADD = \
    $(GST_PLUGINS_BASE_LIBS) -lgstvideo-$(GST_MAJORMINOR) \
    ...